# Submit Campaign Monitor form data using Ajax and With Single Click

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I need to submit the Campaign Monitor form data using Ajax. Currently I have achieved the submission of form data using Ajax but it's taking double click. The user has to click the submit button double times. And i need the data to be submitted on single click.

Html of the Form

```
<form action="https://xxxxxxx.createsend.com/t/d/s/audjhr/" method="post" id="subscribeForm">
       <div class="cv-footer-deserve">
         <input id="fieldEmail" name="cm-audjhr-audjhr" class="cv-news-input input-group-field " type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" value="" aria-label="Enter your email" required />
         <button type="submit" class="subscribe cv-news-btn"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
       </div>  
     </form>
```

Script for the Form

```
$(function () {
    $("#subscribeForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON(
        this.action + "?callback=?",
        $(this).serialize(),
        function (data) {
            if (data.Status === 400) {
              // error msg 
            } else { 
              // success msg 

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: In your actual code the ids do match, right …?

Comment: @CBroe, in the above info, i just added the dummy data. The Id's are matching properly. I'll edit my question so that there will be no confusion.

Comment: Does the user have to click twice for your submit handler to fire? Or does the first click cause an AJAX request already, but it is faulty for some reason? Use browser dev tools to verify.

Comment: Yes CBroe, User has to click twice for form submission. I even checked in the inspect element too, but the ajax call happens on 2nd click.

Comment: Does the button have any event handlers attached itself?

Comment: The Above is the proper code itself. No other event handler attached.

Comment: Replacing the getJSON call with a simple console.log shows that this fires the submit event on the first button click already (provided, the user entered a _valid_ e-mail-address already, so that form validation does not prevent it) - https://jsfiddle.net/xfo577cs/ So if it doesn’t work that way in your page with other stuff around it, then you need to go and figure out what exactly is interfering.

Comment: CBroe, Even i checked in two different ways,

Firstly, i checked by alerting the msg, at the same location where you placed the console.log().

Secondly, i tried by placing the alert msg inside the getJSON , then the ajax didn't work. Now i am trying to figure this out.